# Php's json_decode and firefox's javascript compatibility

Tags: php, javascript, drupal, compatibility, json

it appears if you have something like

```
var my_var = {"foo" : "bar"};
```

in javascript (with firefox at least) and post it to a php server you will receive a string like

```
{foo:"bar",}
```

on the server side.  But json_decode in php doesn't like the trailing ',' or the lack or quotes around 'foo'.  Is there a nice way to clean up the received json string?

The json object is sent with the drupal module json services.

**EDIT:** This question can be closed.  The badly formed json is due to badly written js in the drupal module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What code are you using to POST the data? Make sure you're using something like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: I should check.  I'm using drupal's json_service modulue.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be the crux of the problem.  A badly written json encoder